# Is there a performance difference by wrapping the code in an immediately invoked lambda expression?

Tags: c++, lambda

Here is some code:

```cpp
void f() 
{
    // stuff
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

It is also possible to write it in a strange way like this using lambdas instead of braces:

```cpp
void f() 
{
    // same stuff as above
    [&]{
        // same code as above
    }();
}
```

Will there be any performance difference between the two versions?

According to my checks, there is no difference in generated assembly in clang when compiled with optimizations, so I assume there will be no performance overhead. But is this always the case?

Comment: The first snippet is incrementing `a` in a scope while the second one is using lambda.

Comment: @tony-tannous I know lol. The question is about performance under compiler optimisations.

Comment: From testing a short program, both seem to compile down to the exact same assembly WITH optimizations enabled. WITHOUT optimizations enabled the very small program increased it's size by about 25%-33%. I would assume it would be the same results in a program of any size.

Comment: @lily I think the same. But was interested if it could be wrong.

Comment: I assume any decent compiler will find out you're doing `a++` and do it in a single instruction. The question is why write more code which is confusing to simply writing `a++` ?

Comment: @tony-tannous Question is mostly about not `a++`, but about inlining of a function. Instead `a++` can be whatever.

Comment: Then modify the question to ask whether it's better to write an inline function to a lambda expression. I assume this is why you got 2 downvotes and 2 close votes... add more context and someone experienced might be able to answer.

Comment: I think I asked exactly what is needed. Made important part bolder.

Comment: Optimization are up to compilers (with as-if rule), so the only way to be sure is to measure for your target compiler/flags.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP Stay with using braces as braces, that's probably better.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ I mentioned that I am not asking about the beauty of code.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP I am refering to scope functionality, not beauty.

Comment: Even if the final code would have same performance, compiler will probably works harder and take more time to compile with a lot of lambda.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ But the question is about performance...

Comment: @phil1970 True. Also added that questioning the performance of execution.

Comment: Not clear what's stopping you from compiling both versions of the code, benchmarking each version, and easily resolving the performance question. This is a question that you should be able to answer yourself.

Comment: @sam-varshavchik As I wrote in question, I checked it in clang, and compiled result is the same with some snippets. I am asking if there any possibility that it won't. Maybe some capture features can prevent lambda to be inlined or whatever.

Comment: Also not sure what I need to add to question. Most of things were asked in comments, were already written in the question.

Comment: Anyway. Changed title of question to less misleading.

Comment: Of course it's possible that it won't. No C++ compiler is under no obligation whatsoever to optimize any code to any particular degree.

Comment: @sam-varshavchik The question is how is it possible? I can't find an example where any normal compiler won't optimize it.

Comment: It's possible because the C++ standard does not require it. As such, a compiler is not under any obligation to perform any optimization. It's possible that every compiler you tried managed to optimize it. But that does not guarantee anything, whatsoever. It is still unclear exactly what you're asking here. The C++ standard does not require any specific optimization from any compiler. The End.

Comment: Also C++ standard doesn't operate performance in many cases. And what? Question is about compiler. It is not the answer that compiler doesn't have obligations.

Comment: I've edited the question, and voted to reopen. It seems answerable to me.

Comment: To have a better chance of the question being reopened, you should add in the benchmarks that you ran comparing the 2 versions.

Comment: @cigien I didn't use benchmarks. I compared assembly and llvm bitcode. It is always the same

Comment: Oh, I see. Is the assembly always the same regardless of what code you put in there?

Comment: Yes. It is interesting if it can be different in any way. If it will, performance probably will be different somehow. I tried to create lots of variables to make capture feel bad. But didn't succeed. Assembly is always the same to me. I think these `[&]{ ... }()` do not affect performance at all. But still not sure for 100%. So it is the reason why I asked.

Comment: I know it's probably not my place, but consider changing your username to something slightly shorter.. Perhaps ChiPPy, or CPlusPlus or well.. anything shorter :)

Comment: @scratte I was thinking about it. My nickname symbolizes the dualism of my feelings to C++. In one way it is easy. In another it is hard. In one way it is straightforward, in other it is very strange. I hope one day I will make a farm with ostriches and will be happy.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP I see :D I think your username also may bring up feelings in other users too. This post was closed & deleted. And I don't really know why.. I thought your username may have been a factor :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance is hard to measure. Yet in this case it's still reasonable to reason about it.

Every lambda is actually its own class with `operator()` implemented. This class has the same characteristics as one written in an unnamed namespace. Some relevant elements: its visibility is limited to the `.cpp` file and linked to it, it doesn't need to expose function pointers in the `.obj` file.

What could a compiler do differently with an immediately invoked lambda? Not much actually: it can prevent inlining it. In my experience this has the same behavior as unnamed functions: either the function is too large or it's used multiple times. This last could be the result of a function returning a lambda.

If the function is too large, than it could be that some paths where the function isn't called are faster by not inlining it.
If it's called multiple times, it enlarges your binary to inline it twice, which could slow it down.

To me, the bigger risk is that you call some templated function like `std::sort` with a lambda and copy that function body all over the place to bloat your binary. However as these were already templates before and `std:: function` is known for its measurable performance effects, I don't think it's worth the effort.

That said, I use lambdas all over the place. I even provide class templates that have them as members in performance critical code. Lambdas are considered zero overhead, though depending on how you use them you could find edge cases where a flow in your program slows down.

Some last piece of advice, even in a language like C++, readability is important. Having large lambdas isn't considered readable. I've seen style guide rules limiting it to 5 or 10 lines.
Immediately invoked lambdas have their uses, however, for your example this actually is only overhead from the reader's perspective.

Go and measure! If you have performance critical code, write a performance test for continuous monitoring and run a profiler from time to time to see where time is spent.